# How to display date specific data in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

**Hi,**

I want to display date specific data through MySQL query, i am using the query below;

```
SELECT SUM(qa_effort) 
FROM tbl_uat 
WHERE product='DAS' 
    AND uat_start_date >= '$date1'
```

The query above is displaying data for uat_start_date not only for **>** but also for **<**, what could be the possible reason?

PHP Code:

```
<?php       
$date1 = $_POST["date3"];    
$date2 = $_POST["date4"];

if (is_null($date2) || $date2 === '' ){
$cmsc= mysql_query("SELECT SUM(qa_effort) 
FROM tbl_uat 
WHERE product='DAS' 
   AND uat_start_date >= '$date1'");

while ($cresult = mysql_fetch_array ($cmsc))
$arrda2[0] = $cresult[0];
echo $arrda2[0];
}
?>
```

In tbl_uat the column uat_start_date type is date.

**Thanks
Regards**

Comment: Some example data and the data type of your date column would help

Comment: The precise reason is in your condition. If you're expecting another, more clear answer - then ask more clearly (i.e. provide your sample data e t.c.)

Comment: give a sample of the variable $date1

Comment: Is uat_start_date of type dattime in the table? And is date1 both date and time or just date?

Answer (score 0):

1. [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php?rq=1)
2. `mysql_*` is deprecated. Use `mysqli_*` or `PDO` instead.

In prepared statement example it will look like this:

```
$date1 = $_POST["date3"];    
$date2 = $_POST["date4"];

if (is_null($date2) || $date2 === '' ) {
    $q = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT SUM(qa_effort) 
        FROM tbl_uat 
        WHERE product="DAS"
        AND uat_start_date >= ?
    ');

    $q->bind_param('s', $date1);
    $q->execute();

    $q->bind_result($sum);

    while ($q->fetch()) {
       echo $sum;
    }
}
```

[`mysqli` documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)

Of course you shoulde validate if `$date1` is date in proper format, `Y-m-d` for example.